# Retrieve objects in array if property matches another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, object, angular6

I want to create a new array containing contact objects if the value property in contacts matches the values in `selectedContact`. Any simpler way to do this?

```
selectedContact: number[] = [0,2] //value
contacts: Contact[] = [{ 
  firstName:"Dan";
  lastName:"Chong";
  email:"danc@mail.com";
  value:0;
},
{ 
  firstName:"Mark";
  lastName:"Wong";
  email:"markw@mail.com";
  value:1;
},
{ 
  firstName:"Layla";
  lastName:"Sng";
  email:"layla@mail.com";
  value: 2;
}]
```

Intended final result:

```
newArray = [{ 
 firstName:"Dan";
 lastName:"Chong";
 email:"danc@mail.com";
 value:0;
},{ 
 firstName:"Layla";
 lastName:"Sng";
 email："layla@mail.com";
 value：2;
}];
```

My current solution:

```
const newArray: Contact[] = [];
this.selectedContact.forEach(index => {
  newArray.push(this.contacts.find(c => c.value === index));
});
```

Comment: Failed to mention how current solution differs from expected result or any errors encountered

Comment: There's definitely a *better* way, but what do you mean by "simpler", what are you looking for?

Comment: What are your criteria for "simpler"? It's difficult to conceive of a simpler method. There might be more efficient ones though, such as creating an index of *contacts* for reuse.

Comment: Sorry I meant a more efficient way to go about doing this, without modifications to the arrays. The current solution provides the desired output but is there a more efficient method e.g. without using a forEach loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terms of performance, it would be better to iterate over `selectedContacts` rather than `contacts`, especially since `contacts` are indexed (as an array) and you are selecting through the index.

Say the length of `contacts` is `N` and the length of `selectedContacts` is `M`.

Since `selectedContacts` is a subset of `contacts`, we know `M <= N`.
For large databases of contacts, this difference could be significant.

The code in the question:

```
this.selectedContact.forEach(index => {
  newArray.push(this.contacts.find(c => c.value === index));
});
```

Has `O(M*N)` since it iterates over `selectedContact` `O(M)` and on each iteration it find a value in `contacts` (`O(N)`).

The code from the accepted answer iterates over `contact` (`O(N)`) and looks for a value in `selectedContact` which is `O(M)`. This makes the algorithm equivalent, with `O(N*M)`

In your example, you already have a cheap way of looking up contacts by number since `contacts` is an array and your indexes are simply the index in the array.

This means you can use code like this:

```
return this.selectedContact.map(index => this.contacts[index]);
```

Since accessing an array element by index has `O(1)`, this would have `O(M)` which is the smallest of the sizes.

If you can't use the array index as a key, you can use other data structures, like a `Map` where the id is the key, and the contact is the value. This would have similar lookup speeds (roughly `O(1)`).

Comment: I see. Thanks for your detailed explanation!! :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

> The `filter()` method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.

and [Array.prototype.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

> The includes() method determines whether an array includes a certain element, returning true or false as appropriate.

**Working Code Example:**

```js
var selectedContact = [0,2];
var contacts = [{ 
  firstName: "Dan",
  lastName: "Chong",
  email: "danc@mail.com",
  value: 0
},
{ 
  firstName: "Mark",
  lastName: "Wong",
  email: "markw@mail.com",
  value: 1
},
{ 
  firstName: "Layla",
  lastName: "Sng",
  email: "layla@mail.com",
  value: 2
}]
let newArray =  contacts.filter(c => selectedContact.includes(c.value));

console.log(newArray);
```

Comment: @iBlehhz—yes, but "works" is not a measure of efficiency. ;-) This will be efficient where *selectedContacts* is small, but if it's not, an indexed solution may be better (assuming the cost of creating the index can be recovered).